# Groovy function without parenthesis and argument starting with capital letter causing error

Tags: groovy

I have a class that holds a list of ingredients and provides a function SERVE that prints those ingredients for now.

```
class CookDSL {
  List<String> ingredientsToCook

  CookDSL(List<String> ingredients){
     ingredientsToCook=ingredients
  }

  void SERVE(Closure closure){closure(ingredientsToCook)}
}
```

Here is the DSL function that returns an instance of above class:

```
CookDSL COOK(List<String> ingredients){
  new CookDSL(ingredients)
}
```

Now I can use this DSL as shown below and works fine by printing all ingredients:

```
def ingredients = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
COOK ingredients SERVE {it-> println(it)}
```

Output:

```
[X, Y, Z]
```

To maintain consistency in above DSL, I tried naming ingredients as Ingredients and Groovy didn't liked it.

```
def Ingredients = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
COOK Ingredients SERVE {it-> println(it)}
```

Output:

```
startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 16: unexpected token: Ingredients @ line 18, column 10.
   COOK Ingredients SERVE {it-> println(it)}
        ^

1 error
```

It works fine if Ingredients variable is surrounded with parenthesis:

```
def Ingredients = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
COOK(Ingredients) SERVE {it-> println(it)}
```

Output:

```
[X, Y, Z]
```

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if there is a limitation in Groovy on using variables starting with capital letters in certain situations?

Groovy version: 2.3.8

Comment: Classes start with capitals, variables shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

As @tim_yates stated, the capital letters are probably confusing the parser, maybe it understands them as class identifiers. I've usually seem [DSLs uncapitalized](http://www.slideshare.net/glaforge/going-to-mars-with-groovy-domainspecific-languages).

```
class CookDSL {
  List<String> ingredientsToCook

  void serve(Closure closure){closure(ingredientsToCook)}
}

CookDSL cook(List<String> ingredients){
  new CookDSL(ingredientsToCook: ingredients)
}

def ingredients = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
cook ingredients serve {it-> println(it)}
```

If you set the result to a var, it doesn't complain. Probably it is not ambiguous anymore:

```
def COOK = { ingredients -> new CookDSL(ingredientsToCook: ingredients) }

def Ingredients = ["ribs", "bacon", "pineapple"]
def cooked = COOK Ingredients SERVE { "cooked $it" }
assert cooked == ["cooked ribs", "cooked bacon", "cooked pineapple"]
```